# Phonegap ios-deploy ownership and licensing

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, ionic4

I needed to build my Ionic 4 app with
`ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"` but I got an error message from Cordova saying :

> CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'ios-deploy was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.9.2 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy into your path, or do \'npm install -g ios-deploy\''

I got the package using `npm remove -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true` because you have to use``unsafe-perm=true` in order for it to work. When I got everything my app successfully compiled for Xcode.

However, when I went to the Phonegap Github for IOS Deploy, I was wondering why https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy is redirect to https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy. Was there a change in ownership? Is Phonegap deprecated? Also I noticed the license was GPL v3. Does this mean if I use this tool to compile my app, I have to release my source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/issues/369#issuecomment-447615691

This should clear things up for both ownership and license of the software